# Game Center: Matchmaking

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

In my card playing game I am trying to create a match, which, for a part, works;

```
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)match {

self.match = match;
match.delegate = self;
if (!_matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Ready to start match!");
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameVC"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [viewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    //[viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

After a match is created successfully I want the `GKMatchmakerViewController` to be dismissed and I want the "vc" `UIViewController` to be shown. In the above example this is accomplished, but the `GKMatchmakerViewController` does not get dismissed.

If I remove the comment quotes it will be loaded after it got dismissed somehow and if I place the line above the `presentViewController` line I get an error stating that I am trying to present a view controller on a view controller that is not in the view hierarchy.

How do I dismiss the GKMVC and show the "vc" at the "same" time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dismiss the `GKMatchMakerViewController`, then use your current view controller to present the new modal:

```
if (!_matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Ready to start match!");
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameVC"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Edit: A trick to get the current root view controller is `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController`. So you should be able to present your modal with this:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand what you're saying, but my peace of code is inside a `GameKitHelper` Class. Calling self is not possible, because it will give an error stating `presentViewController:...` is not a visible interface in `GameKitHelper` Class. To be clear: this is a custom `NSObject` Class and not a `UIViewController` Class.

Comment: @Niels Ah, understood. What's the name of your AppDelegate class? Just AppDelegate?

Comment: Does the `rootViewController` method above work @Niels?